# Altering immutable field _id error Mongo DB .net

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb

I keep getting this error:

> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Command
> findAndModify failed: After applying the update, the (immutable) field
> ‘_id’ was found to have been altered to _id: BinData(3,
> 00000000000000000000000000000000).) —>
> MongoDB.Driver.MongoCommandException: Command findAndModify failed:
> After applying the update, the (immutable) field ‘_id’ was found to
> have been altered to _id: BinData(3,
> 00000000000000000000000000000000).

**I'm not trying to change the _id I'm just filtering on id.
The record/document I update the old document with don't have Id I just want to update all the other fields/keys.**

The code:

```
public T UpsertRecord<T>(string table, Guid id, T record)

{
    var collection = db.GetCollection<T>(table);

    var filter = Builders<T>.Filter.Eq("_id", id);

    Task task = collection.FindOneAndReplaceAsync<T>(filter, record, new FindOneAndReplaceOptions<T, T> { IsUpsert = true });

    task.Wait();

    return record;


}
```

Below is the data im trying to post/update()responsePerson.Id:

```
  //Update data
    const string testNameUpdate = "MrSnail";
    const int testTotalUpdate = 2;
    var testPersonUpdate = new TestObj { name = testNameUpdate, total = testTotalUpdate };
    var responseUpdate = _mongoDBFeedClient.UpsertRecord(collectionName, responsePerson.Id, testPersonUpdate);
```

I have tried replaceone method and such.

I’m using Atlas Cloud Mongo DB and its “sharded”. I don’t know if it have anything to do with this but it might.
I don’t wanna change the id just update all the rest of the values id the document exists if it doesn´t I wanna create it.

Comment: Did you tried with `ReplaceOneAsync()` ?

Comment: Yes I have tried that.

Comment: you can't use `FindOneAndReplace` if your `record` doesn't have an id property. you should be using `UpdateOne` and specify all properties except for the id property to update. here's a more convenient [alternative](https://mongodb-entities.com/wiki/Entities-Update.html#update-all-properties)

Comment: I'm trying to add an object. But if it exists I want to update it can updateOne do that to?